# Downloading a file using a windows CMD line using wget/curl

Tags: windows, http, curl, command-line-interface, wget

I have a client [Windows 10 VM] and a server [say a linux based VM].

I have Apache running on the Linux Server.

I have a file on the linux server that I want to download on my windows client.

I want to do it in 2 ways from the windows CMD:
-Using curl
-using wget

I tried the foll commands on my windows CMD. But doesnt work. Is something wrong with my CLI?

```
curl http://x.x.x.x/home/abc/ -O test.zip
wget http://x.x.x.x/home/abc/ -O test.zip
```

Comment: *But doesnt work.* is very vague description, please add more details if possible.

Answer (score 0):

From **curl** side, most probably curl.exe is missed on Windows Client machine or could not find it. One of the options is to download curl:

1. Download curl zip for Windows from this page: https://curl.se/download.html
2. Unzip and you will find the ..\bin\curl.exe
3. Also add ...\bin\ to your Path variable in System Settings.

To use **wget** in Windows, you can follow this link and it worked for me: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/using-wget-command-in-windows-10-environment-d766b8f526e9

Short tutorial:

1. Download the [GnuWin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/wget/1.11.4-1/wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=excellmedia) setup
2. Install it
3. Open the wget directory
4. Add to Environmet Variables as well.

Comment: I just looked at GnuWin on sourceforge .. it has not had any activity in 4 years as of today, it is possible that it still works. I have not looked at the curl alternative yet